# Derivative of the function of random variable

Tags: stochastic-processes, st.statistics, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, machine-learning

Suppose we have a function $\phi(X)$  of random variable $X$. Suppose both of $\phi(X)$ and $X$ are random variables. If $\phi$ is differentiable, how to calculate the derivative of $\phi(X)$ w.r.t. $X$? for example, if $\phi(X)=stand(X)=\frac{X-E(X)}{std(X)}$ (suppose $E(X)$ and $std(X)$ exist), how to calculate $\frac{d\phi(X)}{dX}$? I knew that if we assume the approx. distribution of $X$ exists using LLN or CLT, we can just using mean and std of Gaussian distribution. But how to get a general form of the derivative $d(stand(X))/dX$, $d(EX)/X$ and $d(std(X))/dX$? how to define the limitation and rules of derivatives in this case?

Background of this problem:

Suppose I trained a neural network with standardisation of the data following $(X-EX)/std(X)$. The input is $x(t)$ and output is $y(t)$. How can I calculate the sensitivity of this trained network (basically the $dy(t)/dx(t)$)? if I multiply $(1+\epsilon)$ to $x(t)$, the $1+\epsilon$ will disappear after standardisation. So what should I do? I tried to add a perturbation to the standardized input $X'$ which is $(X-mean(X))/(std(X))$. But after the perturbation what I got is $dy(t)/d(standard(x(t)))$ rather than $dy/dx$. So I also need the ratio of $dx/d(standard(x))$ where $standard(x)$ is $(x(t) - mean(x(t)))/std(x(t))$.

We can assume $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ is a $N$-order Markov process.

So how to calculate the $dx/d(standard(x))$? thanks a lot!

Comment: If $X$ is a constant distribution then the standardization is just a linear function of $X$. I think in practice what people do is they train the network with standardized data and then in execution they take chunks of inputs and standardize them and then feed in. In any case this probably isn't the place. Maybe try https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hi @SeanEberhard, thanks for your comments! But regardless of the background, how to calculate the dEX/dX, dEX^2/dX and d(stand(X))/dX given X is a RV with finite EX and EX^2? I think this question is interesting.

Comment: And if we use test data which may come from a new distribution, the standardisation may changed...

Comment: The function  $\phi$ induces one between tvs's  of random variables and there is a well-developed differential calculus for such functions, particularly for the Banach space case.  The derivative of such a function at a point is a continuous linear operator on the space.